# How to use winobject withouch mouse pixels

Tags: qtp

- Browser("Echo'Net - Home_2").WinObject("DirectUIHWND").Click 743,22
- I the object identified here as winobject ,has two buttons has 2 buttons open and save
- I need to click on one of them but without specifying mouse pixels
- Is there any simple way for the same
- FYI- Naive to QTP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `.GetTextLocation` to find the location of the text, then click on it.

```
posLeft = -1
posTop = -1
posRight = -1
posBottom = -1 
Set myObj = Browser("Echo'Net - Home_2").WinObject("DirectUIHWND")

If myObj.GetTextLocation ("Open", posLeft, posTop, posRight, posBottom) Then
    ' the text was found within the object, click in the middle.
    myObj.Click posLeft + (posRight - posLeft)/2, posTop + (posBottom - posTop)/2
End If
```

Comment: Hey hi, great work ... :-) thanks a lot :-) ,and also thank you stack overflow, one of the best ways for help when i am stuck :-)

Comment: If this answer solves your question, consider to mark it as Accepted. You enable others with the same question to see that there is a solution and it also disappears from the 'unanswered questions list'. As a last benefit, it rewards the answerer with fictional internet points, encouraging answering more questions.